# Profile Attribute/Field Mapping with Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Is there any limitations on mapping fields between Salesforce and Marketing Cloud. I am asking from below 2 points -

1. Is there a max limit on the no. of fields that can be mapped between All Subscribers and Salesforce?
2. I am not able to map any boolean fields in Salesforce. How to do this?

Comment: Any suggestion guys ?